# Proof by using taylor series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

So, everyone that took Single Variable Calculus (calc 1) should be familiar with Taylor Series.

Now, I have a question:

How do I show that:

$$\log(2)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}$$
and that
$$\log(5)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{3^n}{n2^{n}}$$

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first identity can be shown using the fact that $$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{n}}{n}.$$The second identity is incorrect since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{n2^n}\neq0.$$

Comment: @Ethan You can't have convergence of $\sum a_n$ if $a_n\not\to 0$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff lol my bad thought it was $\frac{2^n}{3^n}$

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Taylor expansion $$f(x)=f(a)+f^\prime(a)(x-a)+\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+...$$

and let $f(x) = \log(x), a=1$, thus getting $$ \log(x) = (x-1) - \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 + \frac{1}{3}(x-1)^3 - \frac{1}{4}(x-1)^4 + \dots$$

Now, plug in $x=2$ in the formula above, and you're done with the first part. Can you see how to do the second one?

Answer (score 0):

To get $\log(5)$, take your formula and put $x = -4/5$ into it.